# EmbedReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I was trying to make a bot and knew nothing about this I did some research on it, the bot and everything was okay so I then tried to make an embed for it, my intention is for it to look like a game profile I saw a coding sheet on `https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/discord.js+embed+dm` and filled it out in the layout I wanted but `"message.channel.send({embed: {", "ReferenceError: message is not defined"` kept popping up when I tried to run it, my code is

````
{
    "content": "||__`ARCADIA`__||  ```js\nfunction foo(bar) {\n  console.log(bar);\n}\n\nfoo(1);```",
    "embed": {
     "title": "Profile",
     "description": " ```\nname```",
     "url": "https://discordapp.com",
     "color": 5301186,
     "timestamp": "2020-08-05T22:30:42.588Z",
       "footer": {
        "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/738032536462163978.png?v=1/embed/avatars/0.png",
        "text": "An invitation to meet my blade"
       },
       "thumbnail": {
         "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/739919002121404446/740768912857104474/698661715742556200.png"
       },
       "image": {
         "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/739919002121404446/740029844926234744/Steward.Arknights.full.2929188.png"
       },
       "author": {
         "name": "author name",
         "url": "https://discordapp.com",
         "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/739919002121404446/740769663260295198/2946824.jpg"
       },
       "fields": [
         {
           "name": "Level",
           "value": "100"
          },
          {
           "name": "Zells",
           "value": "1000000"
          },
          {
           "name": "Guild",
           "value": "Zen Rizor"
          },
          {
           "name": "SPIRT",
           "value": "Steward",
           "inline": true
          },
          {
           "name": "LEVEL",
           "value": "26",
           "inline": true
         }    
       ]
     }
   }
````

Also, I have made changes to the original code

Comment: Format your post correctly pls. What typeof is message? Where is the var declaration?

Comment: this is a json file of the embed thankfully it's displayed better

Comment: added it word be appreciated if this could be converted into a working discord.js embed which I can send

Comment: Could you explain what the code you have provided is? Is it a MessageEmbed object? Also, please provide the part of the code that is causing the problem, otherwise, we cannot help you.

Comment: const Discord = require("discord.js")

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
const embed = {
  },
    }
  ]
};
message.channel.send(embed)

Comment: it is an embed object

Comment: const embed = {
      ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'embed' has already been declared

was the error message

Answer (score 0):

You did not declared any `message` variable where you are using it and the bug is.

Comment: const Discord = require("discord.js")

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
const embed = {
  },
    }
  ]
};
message.channel.send(embed)

I don't know of the bug stuff